# Google Play App Review doesn't show App Version code or name

Tags: google-play, developer-console

I have released an app on play store, and have received some reviews. In google play developer console, I could not see the version of app in few of the reviews. This is what I found under the APPLICATION heading.

`Version code — Version name —`

I tried searching around, but could not find any explanation for these to be absent. What may be the possible reasons?

Comment: It seems to happen with devices from many manufacturers, and different versions of Android.

Comment: I too have the same problem, I think the user might have downloaded the apk outside of Play store.

Answer (score 21):

I raised a ticket with Google play and got this response, hope it helps someone.

> Hi Satheeshwaran,
>
> Thanks for contacting Google Play Developer Support!
>
> Regarding your concerns, the circumstance that the version code is
>   absent from users' reviews/comments normally results from the fact
>   that single use, who left comments on your app, has multiple devices,
>   in all of which your app was installed. The versions of your apps
>   installed on the multiple devices are different; therefore, the system
>   is unable to distinguish which version the specific user is currently
>   using.
>
> Thanks for your understanding and continued support.
>
> We hope this helps answer your question. If we can assist you further,
>   please let us know.
>
> Regards, Pepper Google Play Developer Support

Comment: Thanks, that helped... Would be so much esier if they wrote "multiple" instead of "---"